# Getting "The resource cannot be found." when I use HttpPost attribute on an action-method that a jQuery ajax-post points to

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

II'm developing an ajax comment form in my .Net MVC project.

So far, I get a "The resource cannot be found" error,
*UNLESS* I remove the HttpPost attribute from the action method -- then it works.

But for clear reasons, I want the post filter ... so **what am I doing wrong??**

Here's the form (labels and other irrelevant markup removed):

```
    <form action="/SubmitComment">
        <input class="commentFormCommenter" id="Commenter" name="Commenter" type="text" value="" />
        <input class="commentFormEmail" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
        <textarea class="commentFormBody" cols="20" id="Body" name="Body" rows="2"></textarea>
        <input id="PublicationId" name="PublicationId" type="hidden" value="3862" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
    </form>
```

...and I want to  hi-jax it with jQuery like this:

```
$('form[action$="comment"]').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('.tester').text('successful round-trip.');
        }
    });
});
```

...to an ActionMethod in my MVC project:

```
public class CommentController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitComment(string Commenter, string Email, string Body, int PublicationId)  
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
        // AT THIS POINT, SUCCESS IS AN EMPTY PAGE
    } 

}
```

... the route is mapped simply:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "",
    "SubmitComment",
    new { controller = "Comment", action = "SubmitComment" }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just needed to add

```
method="Post"
```

to the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try simplifying your code:

```
$('form[action$="comment"]').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('.tester').text('successful round-trip.');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Faust, when you look at the request with FireBug can you see it being sent? What does the server sends as response?

Comment: Darin, seems my problem was (oh boy) I didn't specify the method in the form tag (doh!). Guess I would have thought post is default for forms.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `HttpPost` try with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`.